# Write file to s3 bucket with Exceljs

Tags: amazon-s3, exceljs

The following script below queries from mySql and stores the results in excel locally. The issue I'm trying to resolve is to save it to the S3 bucket instead on my computer. I have some experience with AWS and can bridge a connection to AWS to read files from the S3 bucket but I am having a hard time resolving this problem. Thanks!

I found the following code but could not integrate it with what I have already wrote.

```
const s3 = new aws.S3(/* put your s3 configuration here */);
const stream = new Stream.PassThrough();
const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
// Add images of cats to workbook

workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
    .then(() => {
        return s3.upload({
            Key: PATH_IN_S3,
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Body: stream,
            ContentType: CONTENT_TYPE_EXCEL
        }).promise();
    })
    .then(/* do whatever */)
    .catch(/* handle error */);

Here is what is currently working locally:


const reconQuery = 'SELECT T1.Database_ID, Lease_Description, SUM(BR_Current_Month_Cash - BR_Current_Month_Cash_Client) total, SUM(CAM_Current_Month_Cash - CAM_Current_Month_Cash_Client) total2, SUM(TAX_Current_Month_Cash - TAX_Current_Month_Cash_Client) total3, SUM(Insurance_Current_Month_Cash - Insurance_Current_Month_Cash_Client) total4, SUM(Sales_Tax_Current_Month_Cash - Sales_Tax_Current_Month_Cash_Client) total5  FROM `lq 2` AS T1  INNER JOIN `cd 2` AS T2 ON T1.Database_ID = T2.Database_ID GROUP BY Database_ID'


  connection.query(reconQuery,
    function (err, reconQuery, field) {

      const jsonReconData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reconQuery));


      let workbook = new excel.Workbook(); //creating workbook
      let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Month 2'); //creating worksheet

      //  WorkSheet Header
      //  WorkSheet Header
      worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Database ID', key: 'Database_ID', width: 10 },
        { header: 'Lease Description', key: 'Lease_Description', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Base Rent Difference', key: 'total', width: 30 },
        { header: 'CAM Difference', key: 'total2', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Tax Difference', key: 'total3', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Insurance Difference', key: 'total4', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Sales Tax Difference', key: 'total5', width: 30 },
      ];

      // Add Array Rows
      worksheet.addRows(jsonReconData);



      // Write to File
      workbook.xlsx.writeFile("month2.xlsx")
        .then(function () {
          console.log("file saved!");
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out if anyone is interested:

```js
    const stream = new Stream.PassThrough();
    const workbook = new excel.Workbook();
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Month 1'); //creating worksheet
         //  WorkSheet Header
      worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Database ID', key: 'Database_ID', width: 10 },
        { header: 'Lease Description', key: 'Lease_Description', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Base Rent Difference', key: 'total', width: 30},
          { header: 'CAM Difference', key: 'total2', width: 30},
          { header: 'Tax Difference', key: 'total3', width: 30},
          { header: 'Insurance Difference', key: 'total4', width: 30},
          { header: 'Sales Tax Difference', key: 'total5', width: 30},
      ];
    // Add Array Rows
    worksheet.addRows(jsonReconData);
    
    workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
        .then(() => {
            return s3.upload({
                Key: 'Month1.xlsx',
                Bucket: 'bucketname',
                Body: stream,
                ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }).promise();
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
          console.log(e.message)
        }).then(function(){
          console.log('after a catch the chain is restored');
        }, function () {
          console.log('Not fired due to the catch');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have the answer already, but i figured I'd add in another, prehaps simpler, solution, using async/await:

```js
  const sheetBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();

  await s3.putObject({
     Bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET',
     Key: 'YOUR/KEY/item.xlsx',
     ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
     Body: sheetBuffer,
   });
``
```